# Academically accepted appropriate valedictions of a letter (formal and informal)

Tags: valediction, cisce

Is there any recommendation as to what should be the closing valedictions of a letter (formal and informal) regarding the tone and nature of the relationship? Example when to use

1. "Yours sincerely"
2. "Yours affectionately"
3. "Yours truly"
4. "Regards"/"Warm Regards"
5. "Yours faithfully"

I am looking forward to an academically correct answer. Alternatively, can we use "Regards" irrespective of the tone and type of relationship?

Comment: Someone still writes letters?

Comment: What does the tag `cisce` mean?

Comment: By "academically accepted" do you mean that someone at a university will be the recipient of your letter?

Comment: You must recognize that the word **affectionately** is borderline hitting on the recipient, and **Warm Regards** adds a too-personal tone. All others carry no special weight, just as my favorite, **Thank you**.

Comment: cisce  = Council For The Indian School Certificate Examinations
academically accepted = accepted as per school work/assignment/test.

Comment: @Abhijit, it is still not clear what you mean by 'academically accepted'. Writing (real) letters is something different from schoolwork. Is your question perhaps about what will be marked as correct in some schoolwork that requires the students to write **fake** letters?

Answer (score 2):

The convention for formal letters is to use *Yours sincerely* if you are writing to someone by name (whether or not you know them personally) and *Yours faithfully* if writing to an organisation or to an official whose name you don't know.

There are no rules for informal letters. Nowadays, if they are on affectionate terms with the recipient, most people would simply sign *Love, [name].*

Comment: Old school, but what I was taught at my old school.

Comment: It should perhaps be added that most people in the United States are unfamiliar with the *sincerely/faithfully* distinction (although there is no harm in following the distinction when writing to them). Also, *Yours sincerely* is usually just *Sincerely* in the United States (but there is, again, no harm is using the longer formulation when writing to people there as well). Also, there is a range of formulations (including *(Warm) Regards* and *Yours* [by itself]) that are less formal than these but do not imply quite the closeness that *Love* does.